# How to transform a pair of values into a sorted unique array?

Tags: python

I have a result like this:

```
[(196, 128), (196, 128), (196, 128), (128, 196),
 (196, 128), (128, 196), (128, 196), (196, 128),
 (128, 196), (128, 196)]
```

And I'd like to convert it to unique values like this, in sorted order:

```
[128, 196]
```

And I'm pretty sure there's something like a one-liner trick in Python (batteries included) but I can't find one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create the set union of all tuples, then sort the result:

```
sorted(set().union(*input_list))
```

Demo:

```
>>> input_list = [(196, 128), (196, 128), (196, 128), (128, 196),
...  (196, 128), (128, 196), (128, 196), (196, 128),
...  (128, 196), (128, 196)]
>>> sorted(set().union(*input_list))
[128, 196]
```

Comment: Perfect! I just dont get the constructor "`set()`" alone

Comment: @OlivierPons: it is a short-cut; it creates an empty `set()` object that then can be used to produce a union with all the tuples. The alternative would be to convert one of the tuples to a set and produce the union with that one.

Comment: Ok, so may I ask you to add your comment with a working sample of what you just explain, I'm very curious about a working code of what you explained. Thank you very much indeed

Comment: @OlivierPons: well, think about it this way: what should happen when `input_list` is *empty*? You'd have to test if there is at least one element to do what I explained, otherwise `set(input_list[0]).union(*input_list[1:])` would throw an `IndexError` exception. But a union between an empty set and a set with elements is the same thing as the set with elements, so you can *start* a union of multiple objects with an empty set. It is just more compact, simpler, and works in all edge-cases.

Comment: Ok I see now. Thank you very much!